# Strapi custom auth controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, strapi

I'm using Strapi for my API and Back office. Everything works fine except one thing: **I can't figure out how to override the controller that is used for the forgot password feature**. I've tried to follow the documentation, especially this page : https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/admin-panel/customization.html#development-mode but no chance.

Here what I've tried :

1. Create a folder `admin` at the root of the project, inside which I created `controller/Auth.js`. In this file I created my custom forgotPassword function but it's not called.
2. Add the file `admin/config/routes.json`, my controller got the same name but I thought that maybe I need to repeat the route here to override, still not successful.
3. I saw on some page that to get what I was searching I needed to put those files (config/routes.json and controller/Auth.js) inside `/extensions/user-permissions/admin`, but it's still not working.

Whatever I try, it's always the default forgot password controller that is called, from the strapi-admin node modules.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I don't see what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 4):

It's normal, because your are not writing the file in the right place.

So I will help you with that.

First here is the documentation for the customization - https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/concepts/customization.html#plugin-extensions

Then we have to find the file in the code source we want to update.

Here is the function - https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/master/packages/strapi-plugin-users-permissions/controllers/Auth.js#L266

Based on the file path and the way to customize in strapi.
You will have to create a file to this path `extensions/users-permissions/controllers/Auth.js`

Then create a `module.exports` with source code function and the update it.

this should work

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I wasn't able to make it work following your suggestion. I created a file `Auth.js`in `extensions/users-permissions/controllers`. In my file I got a module.exports and my controller `forgotPassword` to overwrite the native function. The controller starts with a `console.log` but it is never called, it still the controller from strapi-admin that gets called. Any idea of what I'm missing ? I read again the doc but can't see what's wrong

Comment: @JiLan I've been searching around for a similar case and I think you may want to also check `resetPassword` instead of `forgotPassword`...